# Сохранение итераторов в multimap

Tags: c++

Есть `multimap<size_t, string>` можно ли сделать что то на подобии `multimap<size_t, iterator>` чтобы хранить Итераторы на 
`multimap<size_t, string>`?

Comment: Так сказать, пуркуа бы и не па? Вполне можно. Нужно ли - вопрос другой...

Comment: @VladD итераторы в map/multimap не инвалидируются при вставке в контейнер. При удалении инвалидируются только итераторы на удаленный элемент.

Comment: @Croessmah: И правда (Стандарт 26.2.6/9.) :) Спутал с вектором, судя по всему. Спасибо!

Comment: multimap<size_t, multimap<size_t, string>::iterator>